# JavaFx：How can I centralised a layout when in full screen?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Making the window to be full screen when user clicked full screen button, but I want  the content not to resize, I want to centralised it.
Like this:
[image: Making the window to be full screen, but the content not.]

How can I do this in javafx?
Thank you all guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping your content into another Pane (e.g. [StackPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html)).
Make sure, your content will not grow into the size of the outer pane. You can achieve this e.g. by setting the max width/heigth to take the preferred size.

Simple FXML example:

```
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: red;" StackPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Really helpful!